# Ubuntu Hash Sum Incorrect

Tags: apt, updates, 20.04, hash

I tried to install:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- Xubuntu 20.04
- Kubuntu 20.04

But, post install on execute `sudo apt-get update`, I received the message "Hash Sum mismatch"

What is the problem?

I tried:

```bash
apt clean
apt-get clean
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Comment: What computer do you use and what else, apart from Ubuntu, is there on your computer?

Comment: Did you install the three distros together or one after another?

Answer (score 0):

To solve hash sum mismatch you simply need to enable `acquire-by-hash` which is available in apt 1.2.0 or newer (if you are using Ubuntu Xenial (16.04) or Debian Stretch, or anything newer, you will be running a version of APT that supports this feature).

To enable `acquire-by-hash` do the following:

```
sudo -s
echo "Acquire::By-Hash \"yes\"; ">/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01byhash
apt update
```

For a background on apt and other fixes to your problem, see [this](https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2016/09/27/fixing-apt-hash-sum-mismatch-consistent-apt-repositories/) helpful webpage.

---

If the above doesn't work for you you can try the following commands:

```
sudo -s    
apt-get clean
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
apt-get clean
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Executed the command mentioned, but did not solve the problem, the file 01byhash was created in the correct location with the syntax: Acquire::By-Hash "yes"; But I still get hash sum incorrect

Comment: @RodrigoJoséPetreça I edited my answer, please try and let me know if it works

Comment: commands executed.
Same problems